# PHP Opacity multiplication

Tags: php, rgba

So I have a string like this "rgba(66, 66, 66, 1)" how could I multiply the last digit or number of it by 255. It would also need to be compliant with rgba(214, 234, 216, 0.6) for example. I wasnt sure how to do this as the rgb aspect and the opacity could be different every time.

Comment: Do you mean `rgba(66, 66, 66, 1)` as a literal text or an image pixel property?

Comment: regex matching of the string would give you the individual parts. From there you could cast to a number and do your math.

Comment: Literal text, I am getting a value from a color selector input. I transfer it to php through post. I would need to multiply the A or alpha aspect by 255.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working function that parses the rgba format and returns an array with each color, along with scaling a float alpha value out to 0-255. It also clamps all the values between 0-255 to prevent overflows outside that range. If an invalid rgb string is passed in, the function returns false.

Function ([demo](https://3v4l.org/1iUh1)):

```
/**
 * Parses an RGBA string and returns and array with each color
 * @param  string $str The RGBA string, ex: "rgba(66, 66, 66, 1)"
 * @return array       Returns an array with each r, g, b and a value or false if an invalid string is passed in.
 */
function parseRGBA($str){
    //match the rgba string and get it's part
    if(preg_match('/rgba\( *([\d\.-]+), *([\d\.-]+), *([\d\.-]+), *([\d\.-]+) *\)/i', $str, $m)){
        $out = array(
            'r'=>intval($m[1]), //get the red
            'g'=>intval($m[2]), //get the green
            'b'=>intval($m[3]), //get the blue
            'a'=>round(floatval($m[4]) * 255), //get the alpha and scale to 0-255
        );

        //clamp each  value between 0 and 255
        array_walk($out, function(&$v){ $v = min(255, max(0, $v)); });

        return $out;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Example:

```
echo '<pre>';
echo "Normal value: ";
print_r(parseRGBA("rgba(66, 66, 66, 1)"));

echo "Red > 255: ";
print_r(parseRGBA("rgba(660, 66, 66, 1)"));

echo "Green < 0: ";
print_r(parseRGBA("rgba(66, -66, 66, 1)"));

echo "Alpha float (normal): ";
print_r(parseRGBA("rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.6)"));

echo "Alpha overflow: ";
print_r(parseRGBA("rgba(66, 66, 66, 10)"));
```

outputs:

```
Normal value: Array
(
    [r] => 66
    [g] => 66
    [b] => 66
    [a] => 255
)
Red > 255: Array
(
    [r] => 255
    [g] => 66
    [b] => 66
    [a] => 255
)
Green < 0: Array
(
    [r] => 66
    [g] => 0
    [b] => 66
    [a] => 255
)
Alpha float (normal): Array
(
    [r] => 66
    [g] => 66
    [b] => 66
    [a] => 153
)
Alpha overflow: Array
(
    [r] => 66
    [g] => 66
    [b] => 66
    [a] => 255
)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for this it works, However how would you make it so the result is a string and not an array. I assume you would need to use implode. So instead of     [r] => 66
    [g] => 66
    [b] => 66
    [a] => 255 it would just be rgba(66, 66, 66, 255)

Comment: Use the array to build the string again. `$newStr = "rgba( {$ret['r']}, {$ret['g']}, {$ret['b']}, {$ret['a']})";`

Answer (score 0):

simply use an explode, splitting it on the ',' into an array:

```
$arr=explode(',',$string);
```

You'll probably get away with doing a floatval on the 4th item ($arr[3]):

```
$arr[3]=255*floatval($arr[3]);
```

then join it back up with the implode() function (remembering to add back on the ')' our floatval will have lost:

```
$string=implode(',',$arr).")";
```

Should work.